# php error log showing error from previous file version

Tags: php

I have a php file which had legitimate errors on lines 19 and 24. I have since corrected those errors and restructured code. Line 19 is now line 18 and line 19 contains no quotation marks, yet that's what the error log points to which is the old error. Line 24 had an errant curly brace and that error is still showing, though the curly brace no longer appears there.

Ive deleted the error log file and when it regenerates, it regenerates with the old timestamp and old errors. No new errors are displayed.

> [27-Dec-2018 05:26:36 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/inc/myPledges.php on line 19
>   [27-Dec-2018 05:27:08 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/inc/myPledges.php on line 19
>   [27-Dec-2018 05:28:07 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/inc/myPledges.php on line 24

Line 19:

```
$result = $link->query($query); // The Query was malformed and previously showed here, but is now on line 18
```

Line 24:

```
?> //curly brace was here but was deleted
```

The file resides on my dev server and there are no copies of the file anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the old error log file information was appearing in console when opening the error log file from the server. The actual file contents of the error log on the server are different.

Refreshing the console showed the current file contents.

Comment: It may be useful for someone else to remember to refresh their console and/or check file contents vs what is seen in console. I've never come across this before